# Unparsable Date in Java: Basic Calendar instance parse issues with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse the current time and date into this simple date format.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy-kk:mm");
Date datetoday = sdf.parse(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
```

However, I get this.

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue May 17 15:28:36 CDT 2016"

I'm still able to parse Strings like: 5/5/1991-12:00 but when given a Calendar Instance, it blows up. I *really* should have used **JodaTime** from the get go.

How can I just get the current time, into the SimpleDateFormat as it is? As I understood it, the SimpleDateFormat would take in the String and turn it into a Date once its able to parse it in. The parse would see that Tue would go into a ddd area in a SDF and May would go into a MMM if I had that in a simpleDateFormat. I dont. I have MM, and so its blowing up. I can do a M/d/yyyy in the input, so I end up giving it M, while askign for MM, and that still works.

Should I just scrap everything and go with **JodaTime** or is there a line or two that I'm missing?

Comment: I don't understand. If you have a `Calendar` instance, you can get the `Date` directly from it. Why would you need to convert it to a string and parse that string?

Comment: JodaTime?  No, you should be using JDK 8 and the java.time package.

Comment: I was not clear. I have one Date follows the format of MM-dd-yyyy that I want to compare that with the current date, whos Calendar instance doesnt follow that format so they cant be compared.

Comment: What time zone was intended for your example input string? Did you mean noon in Auckland NZ, noon in Paris FR, or noon in Montréal Québec CA?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Joda-Time too is succeeded by java.time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you obtain current date represented as a Java Date object:

```
Date date = new Date();
```

This is how you obtain current date as a formatted string:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy-kk:mm");
String formattedDateString = sdf.format(new Date());
```

You can then further parse it back into a Date:

```
Date date = sdf.parse(formattedDateString);
```

But there is no point in doing that because you already had the Date when you did the .format(...) call, only in your case you used

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
```

which typically gives the same result as

```
new Date()
```

If you want to parse a string into a Date then the string needs to match the format specified in SimpleDateFormat constructor. Date's toString() method that you are using returns a string in a specific format that does not match the format from your example, that's why you are getting the ParseException error.

Answer (score 0):

## String != date-time

Do not confuse a date-time object with a String that represents its value.

You should be working with objects as much as possible. Generate a String only for presentation to the user. When using strings to exchanged data with other software, use only the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

## java.time

The Question and the accepted Answer both use troublesome old legacy date-time classes, now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Your input format is not standard and is confusingly ambiguous. Is that `-12:00` on the end a time zone or a time-of-day? I will guess a time-of-day. That guess means the input lacks any indication of an offset-from-UTC or a time zone. So we parse as a `LocalDateTime` object.

```
String input = "5/5/1991-12:00"
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M/d/uuuu-HH:mm" );
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.format( input , f );
```

> ldt.toString(): 1991-05-05T12:00

A `LocalDateTime` object purposely lacks any [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or time zone. That means it does *not* represent a moment on the timeline, only a rough idea about possible moments. You must assign a time zone to give it meaning.

If the context of your suggestions indicates this input was meant to be in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), apply the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC` to get an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset ( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

> odt.toString(): 1991-05-05T12:00Z

The `Z` on the end of a standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string is short for `Zulu` and [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

On the other hand, if the context indicates a specific time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). What time zone was intended for your example input string? Did you mean noon in Auckland NZ, noon in Paris FR, or noon in Montréal Québec CA?

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone ( z );
```

> zdt.toString(): 1991-05-05T12:00-04:00[America/Montreal]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).